# Flutter: How to upload data to firestore database in background when app is closed at a particular time daily

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, background

I am trying to **upload data** to my **firestore databas**e at **10:30 am and 6 pm daily** whether the app is open or closed in **Android**, in the open state it can be done in the regular method but how to do it when the **app is closed**

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize Android's `WorkManager` to do periodic tasks in the background. Here's an [existing plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) that does this.

Here is an example of scheduling two recurring jobs that have an initial delay and then repeat every day at the same time. You will need to consult the plugin documentation for how to implement the tasks.

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final tenThirtyAmDelay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 10, 30).difference(now);
final sixPmDelay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 18).difference(now);
if (tenThirtyAmDelay.isNegative) {
  tenThirtyAmDelay.add(days: 1);
}
if (sixPmDelay.isNegative) {
  sixPmDelay.add(days: 1);
}

WorkManager().registerPeriodicTask(
  "my1030amTask",
  "my1030amTask",
  initialDelay: tenThirtyAmDelay,
  frequency: Duration(days: 1),
);

WorkManager().registerPeriodicTask(
  "my6pmTask",
  "my6pmTask",
  initialDelay: sixPmDelay,
  frequency: Duration(days: 1),
);
```

Comment: it shows how to do periodically but how to do at a particular time for example 10:30 am?

Comment: You can calculate an initial delay to the desired time and then do periodic for every 24 hours. I will add an example to my answer to help.

Comment: an example will be really helpful, thank you so much, it's bit difficult to visualize the concept and logic